# How can i match a string with another string and return true for it?

Tags: javascript

Well this is my code where m matching a string with username passed and getting result from Api and updating a property isSelected to true if it gets matched but it is not returning true for the same

```js
const userFilter = [{
  userName: 'A Roy'
}, {
  userName: 'John Doe'
}];

const userName = 'JoHN Doe, A Roy';

userFilter.forEach(a => {
  console.log(a.userName.toLowerCase().includes(userName.toLowerCase()));
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete example? Or a https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: suppose userFilter is an array of object [{userName:A Roy},{ userName: John Doe}] and i am mapping through it and userName.tolowecase() ="A roy, John Doe" now m adding a property to isSelected  on the basis of comparison with includes

Comment: The callback in `map` doesn't return anything. It creates an array of `undefined`. Please edit your question and add the code from your comment there.

Comment: Your code works as I expect: https://jsfiddle.net/5or8kdz1/ I guess you expect a different behavior. Please elaborate the problem and add a [mcve]. Are you looking for `userName.toLowerCase().includes(a.userName.toLowerCase())`?

Comment: Check the FIddle i saved it. and run it and you will see false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. In your code, you're checking whether the `userName` of the array elements contain a string. Apparently, you want to check whether the string contains the `userName` of the array elements:

```js
const userFilter = [{
  userName: 'A Roy'
}, {
  userName: 'John Doe'
}];

const userName = 'JoHN Doe, A Roy';

userFilter.forEach(a => {
  console.log(userName.toLowerCase().includes(a.userName.toLowerCase()));
});

userFilter.forEach(a => {
  a.isSelected = userName.toLowerCase().includes(a.userName.toLowerCase());
  a.name = a.userName;
  a.label = a.name;
  a.id = a.UserId;
});
console.log(userFilter);
```

Comment: but in that case is Selected is coming false
userFilter.map((a) => {
          a.isSelected = userName.toLowerCase().includes(a.userName.toLowerCase()); 
          a.name = a.userName;

          a.label = a.name;
          a.id = a.UserId;
        });

Comment: @AbhishekRoy The callback doesn't return anything. Why do you use `map`? That doesn't make sense. It creates an array of `undefined`. Maybe that's the problem? I've edited my answer. You can see that `isSelected` contains the correct value.